# Chrome 80 - Duplicating history entries if Iframe present on page

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, browser-history

I've a strange issue occurring with Chrome. If there is an iframe on a page it is creating an extra history entry in the browser.

So say a page has 3 iframes, we have 3 history entries for the same page when I right-click the back button.

If a page has 4 iframes, we get 4 entries and so on. It seems to only happen in Chrome (current version 80.0.3987.132).

Example page...

https://www.ljmu.ac.uk/study/courses/undergraduates/2020/marketing

The only workaround I have so far is to defer loading the iframe until the user clicks on it like the videos on this page:

https://www.ljmu.ac.uk/international/thinking-of-applying/reasons-to-choose-ljmu

**Is this a known bug?**

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue specific to Chrome 79 & 80. It doesn't occur in the 81 beta. So I guess we just wait 2 weeks for the release.

All other main browsers work as expected.